# Как кастомизировать форму Float action button?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Как кастомизировать форму `Float action button`?

Необходимо сделать из круглой формы овал.

Comment: А Вы пытались уже что-то сделать?

Comment: Поискал в google)) Вообще открыл исходник Float button искал где форма задается. Короче не нашел если бы смог. писать не стал бы сюда

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938804/change-the-shape-of-floating-action-button